# Difference between complete.cases and !is.na

Tags: r, na

I just discovered this new function it seems to me to an improved version of !is.na, maybe wrapped into an `apply(df, 1)`. Am I correct or the following:

```
> a<-c(1,2,4,NA,6,8)
> identical(complete.cases(a), !is.na(a))
[1] TRUE
```

it's not always true?

Comment: `complete.cases` checks row-wise for NA, and if present returns FALSE. It's more useful on a `data.frame` as `!is.na(a)` would return back a matrix of the same dimensions as `data.frame` where as `complete.cases` will return a vector, one for each row of the `data.frame`. In essence `DF[complete.cases(DF), ]` will remove all rows with at least 1 NA which is a handy tool. I've not used them on vectors although the usage you show is perfectly valid.

Comment: Although on vectors a quick benchmark shows that `!is.na` is twice as fast (even though we are talking about 0.05 and 0.1 seconds).

Comment: @Arun -- I didn't see this comment when posting my answer.

Comment: @mnel, no worries, +1. It's as clear as usual :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an atomic vector, `complete.cases` and `is.na` will be identical. For more complex objects this will not be the case.

Eg, for, a data.frame `is.na.data.frame` will return a logical matrix  of the same dimension as the input.

test <- data.frame(a, b =1)

```
is.na(test)
#          a     b
# [1,] FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE
complete.cases(test)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: hi thanks, so you are confirming the `identical(complete.cases(df), apply(df, 1, function(x) any(!is.na(x))))==TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a vector r1 and  matrix/table r2 as below and interpret the results

```
> r1
 [1] 11.3 10.4   NA 11.7 10.8 11.7 10.1  9.8 12.1  1.5  1.8
> r2
    speed mxPH mnO2
60 medium 6.60 11.3
61 medium 6.50 10.4
62 medium 6.40   NA
63   high 7.83 11.7
64   high 7.57 10.8
65   high 7.19 11.7
66   high 7.44 10.1
67   high 7.14  9.8
68   high 7.00 12.1
69 medium 7.50  1.5
70 medium 7.50  1.8
```

**is.na and complete.cases work same way for a vector**

```
> **is.na(r1)**
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> **complete.cases(r1)**
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Now lets see both what both commands give for a 2 dimensional data**

***as you can see is.na acted upon individual value but complete.cases acted on ROW level***

```
> **is.na(r2)**
   speed  mxPH  mnO2
60 FALSE FALSE FALSE
61 FALSE FALSE FALSE
62 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
63 FALSE FALSE FALSE
64 FALSE FALSE FALSE
65 FALSE FALSE FALSE
66 FALSE FALSE FALSE
67 FALSE FALSE FALSE
68 FALSE FALSE FALSE
69 FALSE FALSE FALSE
70 FALSE FALSE FALSE

> **complete.cases(r2)**
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```